# Why is a cash store named as such?

Tags: realism, props, the-ballad-of-buster-scruggs

In the movie, Ballad of Buster Scruggs, there is a store in the town called Cash Store. (To the right of the mirror in the screenshot)

[image]

It is often to see Cash only as a way of accepting payment in the modern world, why would a store back in the old west be named as Cash Store?

Does suggest there were other ways to make payments in addition to cash? What could other means of making a payment be in the old west?

Comment: On credit? It wasn't uncommon for people to offer payment when their harvest came in or  they could sell their herds at market.

Comment: Well, if you didn't want people bartering with potatoes or animal pelts then you'd advertise cash-only =)

Comment: in railroad towns there's also the alternative of company stores working in scrip: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Company_store

Comment: (actually railroad towns were a poor example, mining towns would be a better one, either way, company towns and company stores were a big thing in this era)

Comment: My question would be "why did the writers think that firing a revolver right next to your ear would be a good idea".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The cash store, or general store, was an important part of the mid-19th century services. At times where money could take several forms ([1837–1863: "Free banking" era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_banking_in_the_United_States)) and before the [1863: US National Banking System](https://www.aba.com/about-us/our-story/aba-history/1850-1899), these stores could sell, trade, exchange, lend...etc.

> In the mid-19th century, the general store served as both an intimate and functional location where villagers and people from the surrounding countryside could shop and meet. The keeper of the store held an integral role in the community and operated a central hub for market shopping, **credit practices**, postal requests, public forums, and news exchange. From corsets to patent medicines, the 1850s general store offered a little bit of everything: **cash, barter, and credit**. [Missouri State Museum](https://mostateparks.com/sites/mostateparks/files/JLSHS_Cash-Barter-Credit.pdf)

From [Railroads brought prosperity to Jacksonville in the 1850s](https://www.myjournalcourier.com/news/article/Railroads-brought-prosperity-to-Jacksonville-in-12593906.php), we can see how businesses evolved over the years, and needed to adapt to not only new customers, but also new way of doing business:

> The prosperity of the 1850s brought more money into circulation. In fact, so much cash was in the hands of customers that one successful downtown grocery went to **straight cash trade**.
>
> > “By offering lower prices, they hoped to compete with merchants who still extended credit,” Doyle wrote. “This policy was followed by other merchants but apparently was not popular with farmers in the area; they still relied upon the personal ties with a local merchant in order to secure needed credit, which they then paid off at the next harvest.”

[Retail Stores in the United States 1800-1860](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1245160) explains how it worked: "*the merchandise of the store was exchanged for the various articles produced by villager and settler.Some articles of country produce, however, were in sufficient demand to command cash.*" As the monetary system evolved, this way to make business declined and the stores' importance diminished.

More to read:

1. [First American department stores & Innovations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Department_store#First_American_department_stores_(1825%E2%80%931858))
2. [Money and debts](https://americanhistory.si.edu/american-enterprise-exhibition/merchant-era/money-and-debt)
3. [1800-1849: A History of America's Banks](https://www.aba.com/about-us/our-story/aba-history/1800-1849)

Comment: I'm still not understanding why it would be _labeled_ as "Cash Store" rather than "General Store" or just "Store". What would a customer expect from seeing the sign "Cash Store" that they wouldn't expect from a different merchant? What is the significance of the word "Cash" on the sign?

Comment: @R.M. : because many stores were *not* offering the cash option. As trading/banking was very loose, it was different from one city/state to another. I guess writing it up front was good advertising.

Comment: @OldPadawan - I definitely missed it in your answer:  Some stores did *not* accept *cash*? But they'd do Credit/Trade?  I know you said that the banking back then was hit/miss, but cash is cash, no?  Or was this in the time where different areas of the country/area had their own "cash"/monetary system?  I understand that farmers/etc may not have cash themselves (hence Credit, Trade being necessary), but I don't quite get why a store would not accept cash as a business decision.

Comment: @BruceWayne : I think it's more about *trading* cash with the customer. Either by giving him cash for goods, or lending cash. Some general stores were just like we know them: come in, put goods in your basket, cashier, give cash, get receipt, bye. Some others were exchanging goods for cash, trading cash in one way or another.

Comment: @R.M. it's both a store but also a money exchanger for the various currencies in circulation at the time. These used to be common as dirt e.g. in Europe before the EU and the Euro. Is "Cash Store" any worse than "Bureau de Change" or "Cambiar de Exchange"?